# Recharts Different Size Bar Groups (in React)

Tags: reactjs, graph, charts, bar-chart, recharts

In the bar chart of Recharts, it seems that groups must always have the same number of spaces. Whether or not bars are shown in a particular group, it will always have the same number of spaces as the other groups.

[image]

Even if we removed the green bar from "Page A", the empty space would remain, so that every group has two spaces.

However, I want to create a bar chart in that groups have different number of spaces, corresponding to how many bars each has. Something like below:

[image]

Because my chart is going to have up to 20 bars per group, so obviously, if one of my groups only has 1 bar, I would have 19 empty spaces next to that bar, which is a huge waste of space. I would like each group to contain only the number of spaces that group needs.

............

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be possible in recharts unfortunatley.

There was an issue raised on the topic in 2020, which you can find [here](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1265).

There we a couple of workarounds suggested, one which uses a custom shape for the bar, making the bar width 0 conditionally. However, the width of the group remains unchanged so I don't believe it would suit your use case.